# Update SASS in ruby

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I am working on a project based on ruby. How can I update the SASS engine? My PC has one version, but my project doesn't.

I've tried using `gem update`, but it doesn't update SASS.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bundler, you can just run

```
bundle update sass
```

Without bundler rubygems can install fresh version, but your app may use old one. Try to uninstall older version.

But the best solution to escape such problems - is to use bundler.

Comment: How do I make bundler use a different version of a gem? Because I found it has all the SASS versions installed already

Comment: Using bundler, you can set gems version in Gemfile, like
gem 'sass', '1.0.0'
for example